# ROS Answers SE migration: error rosrun

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I wish make this command "rosrun basic_robot_control joint_control" in my folder but when I make this, I have this problem:

```
[rospack] Error: stack/package basic_robot_control not found
Usage: joint_control loop/one Right/Left ros/file/ros+file [slow/normal/veryfast] [mirror]


[Error] Usage: joint_control loop/one Right/Left ros/file/ros+file [slow/normal/veryfast] [mirror]    (not 1 arguments)
```

I don't understand what's the problem. Can you help me ?!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/107166/error-rosrun/) by [alivero](https://answers.ros.org/users/8946/alivero/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-12-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please copy and paste what you are typing as well as state what your environment is.  Your error message and command do not agree. One says "basic_robot_control" one says "basic_control_robot" which is probably one of your errors.  You also appear to be passing the wrong arguments on the command line  (1 arguments vs 4 or 5 arguments.)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0